# Retrieve TCP MSS value from Socket Buffer

Tags: c, sockets, linux-kernel, netfilter

I am filtering packets on kernel level through LKM/netfilter using attributes from headers (TCP/IP) [linux `tcp.h` and `ip.h`].

Follows an example of the code:

```
static unsigned int Filter(void *priv, struct sk_buff *skb, const struct nf_hook_state *state) {

    struct ethhdr *ethh;
    struct iphdr  *iph;     // ip header struct
    struct tcphdr *tcph;    // tcp header struct
    
    ethh = eth_hdr(skb);
    iph = ip_hdr(skb);

    if (!(iph)){
       return NF_ACCEPT;
    }

    if (iph->protocol == IPPROTO_TCP){ // TCP Protocol
       tcph = tcp_hdr(skb);

       if (iph->tot_len > htons(64)) return NF_ACCEPT;

       if ((iph->ttl > htons(254))
           || (iph->ttl == htons(64) && tcph->window > htons(1024))
           || (iph->ttl <= htons(65) && tcph->window <= htons(1024) && ((iph->frag_off & IP_DF)==0)))
           return NF_DROP;

       return NF_ACCEPT;
        
    }

    return NF_ACCEPT;
}
```

But now I have to include a condition based on **MSS Value**, this criteria was raised through Wireshark analysis and according to [Wireshark Reference](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/t/tcp.html):

- Field Name: tcp.options.mss_val
- Description: MSS Value
- Type: Unsigned integer, 2 bytes

I looked for it here on Stack Overflow and through Google but did not find how to retrieve this `tcp.options.mss_val` from socket buffer (skb).

Please, any idea on how to retrieve it ?

Comment: Which Linux kernel version you are on?

Comment: What is the need for `ethh`? Also seems that `iph` cannot be NULL, so there is no need for such `if`-statement.

Comment: The LKM is being deployed on a kernel 4.19.118-v7+. The `ethh` is not in use.

Comment: Please also show how you register the hook. Is it LOCAL_IN or LOCAL_OUT or whatever?

Comment: `static struct nf_hook_ops simpleFilterHook = {
    .hook = simpleFilter,
    .hooknum = NF_INET_POST_ROUTING,
    .pf  = PF_INET,
    .priority = NF_IP_PRI_FIRST,
#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE < KERNEL_VERSION(4,4,0)
    .owner = THIS_MODULE
#endif
};`

Comment: It's not completely clear, do you want to obtain MSS of the whole local connection of specific packet or you want to obtain MSS values from SYN and SYN,ACK packets?
Are you processing transit or local traffic?

Comment: I am looking for the MSS value for SYN packets and I am using on local traffic

Comment: Are the .window and .ttl fields in network byte order? If so: reorder them (instead of the literals).

Comment: @wildplasser I did not get the point of your comment

Comment: @GustavoBertoli : so sad...